# How to install zipline in ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, apt, zipline

i am try to install zipline in ubuntu 14.04, i am try pip or git both 
when i am try install zipline using pip this error is showa:

```
  najeeb@najeeb:~$ sudo -H pip install zipline
   Collecting zipline
   Downloading zipline-0.8.3.tar.gz (815kB)
   100% |████████████████████████████████| 815kB 161kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy==1.9.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Cython==0.22.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-j_BiQ5/zipline/setup.py", line 199, in <module>
    packages=find_packages('.', include=['zipline', 'zipline.*']),
TypeError: find_packages() got an unexpected keyword argument 'include'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-j_BiQ5/zipline
```

i hope some one help to what the problem
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try updating `setuptools`: the `include` argument to `find_packages` [was added in version 3.3](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/src/4ce518784af886e6977fa2dbe58359d0fe161d0d/CHANGES.txt?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#CHANGES.txt-794). Maybe you're running an older version?

To do so, use:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Comment: i am upload screen shot

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Try this way, it works for me:

```
$ pip install numpy
$ pip install cython
$ pip install -U setuptools
$ pip install zipline
```

Comment: it seems useful for mac install . Zipline writer should get fired

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you try to install zipline in your system. I recommend to use conda environment. First, install anaconda Visit https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python  then create python environment and install the only package for your project.This will not affect you system. after this. create evn.

`conda create --name my_env python=3`

Activate:

`source activate my_env`

Info

`conda info --envs`